# notify user if similar model created _Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model.that I need to if any model with specific field created in database.send a Email to user for notify.I did some search too many apps are there for handling the notify. thats not my concern .I dont know how deploy this structure.any guide or example for this.for example :

```
if x = book.objects.create(title="book1") :
    print("the book created")
```

if this action happend do something.

Comment: Use signals. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to monitor object creation globally the best thing to use is [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/)

Like so:

```
from .models import Book
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def book_created(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.title == 'book1':
       #logic here

post_save.connect(save_profile, sender=Book)
```

you need to stick that post_save.connect() function somewhere where it will be evaluated when the app is run, you can use `app_dir/app.py` for instance.